# Two groups of alphanumeric characters (including letters, numbers, and underscores) separated by one or more whitespace characters

Tags: regex

Fill in the code to check if the text passed has at least 2 groups of alphanumeric characters (including letters, numbers, and underscores) separated by one or more whitespace characters

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"___", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One")) # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) # False
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com for testing and debugging.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"\w\s+\w", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One ")) # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) # False
```

This is my answer that returns what it is asking for,
the key answer is `\w\s+\w`

Answer (score 1):

Use as regex pattern

```
\b\w+\s+\w+\b
```

- `\b` word boundery, marks a start of a word (also works as start of string)
- `\w+` means alphanumeric characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (one or more)
- `\s+` one or more whitespaces
- `\w+` next alphanumeric characters (1+)
- `\b` word boundery (works at string end too)

So try:

```py
import re

def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"\b\w+\s+\w+\b", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One "))  # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO"))  # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01"))  # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs."))  # False
```

If there should be special characters/spaces/... left and/or right of the alphanumeric groups, you must specify it.

Test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com) or [debuggex](https://debuggex.com).

[image: Picture by https://jex.im/regulex/]
Picture by [Regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/) (! The syntax there is for JavaScript !)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

`re.search(r"\w\s+\w", text)`

There are 2 space between " 123  Ready". Since `\s` is only indicated by one whitespace character, we should use `\s+` which indicates one or more whitespace characters like so:

```
print(re.search(r"\w\s\w", "123  Ready Set GO"))
>>> <re.Match object; span=(9, 12), match='y S'>

print(re.search(r"\w\s+\w", "123  Ready Set GO"))
>>> <re.Match object; span=(7, 10), match='e u'>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result = re.search(r"\w+\s", text)
```

Import the re modules
\w searches for all alphanumeric character including underscores
\s searches for white spaces

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.

Comment: This only gets one group followed by a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"\w+\s", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One")) # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) # False
```

Here is your output:
False
True
True
False

Comment: This will match also `One ` (a space about One)  which has only ONE group.

Comment: typo:  should be (a space after One)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"[\w]+[\s]+[\w]", text)
  return result != None
```

The answer is to use `[\w]+[\s]+[\w]` as regex.

Comment: Why using character classes? `\b\w+\s+\w+\b` looks better.

Answer (score 0):

This will match the condition for **2 groups** of alphanumeric characters including underscore separated by **one or more whitespace** characters

```
result = re.search(r"\w+\s.*", text)
```

Clarification:

1. Repeated characters will be searched by *
2. Alphanumeric characters including underscore will be searched by **\w**
3. Space characters will be searched by using **\s**
4. To search character between two will be searched by a combination of a dot(.)

Comment: `.*` would represent ) 0 or more => question is stressing on having at-least 2 groups of alpha-numberic match ?

Answer (score 0):

result = re.search(r"**\b\w*\s\w*\b**", text)

You can try this too.
\b defines the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple one

---

`result = re.search(r"[\w] [\w]", text)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
    result = re.search(r"\w[ ]*[ ]\w", text)
```

"\w[ ]*[ ]\w"

\w: alphanumeric include letter, number and underline "_"

[ ]: a whitespace

\w[ ]*[ ]\w: 2 groups of alphanumeric separated by one or more whitespace characters

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"\w[ ]*[ ]\w", text)
  return result != None

print(check_character_groups("One")) # False
print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) # False
print(check_character_groups("_, _"))#False
print(check_character_groups("_ ,_"))#False
print(check_character_groups("a     z"))#True
```

Comment: Please consider that tabs are whitespaces too. And instead of `[ ]*[ ]` you can use `[ ]+`, and instead of `[ ]` simply ` `. To take all whitespaces use `\s`. So you get `\w\s+\w`. But this answer is already given.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my confusion. It now makes more sense to me!!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
import re
def check_character_groups(text):
  result = re.search(r"\w\w*\s", text)
  return result != None

  print(check_character_groups("One")) # False
  print(check_character_groups("123  Ready Set GO")) # True
  print(check_character_groups("username user_01")) # True
  print(check_character_groups("shopping_list: milk, bread, eggs.")) #False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).